# How to decide and narrow down the broad topics I should get an astronomy internship on?

Tags: undergraduate, research-undergraduate, research-topic, internship, india

This is to inform that I am a third-year Physics Major student. I am enrolled in a five-year dual degree BS-MS programme at IISER Bhopal, India. I had a keen pop-science-like interest in astronomy since childhood. I hardly knew anything on a mathematical basis but was deeply moved by the stuff when I learned about it.

I have a habit of getting deeply into the topic and understanding the core of it. I am managing fine in my coursework, but I am not able to figure out what I really want to try out. I garnered a fascination for programming in my first year and, gained Web and app dev skills, learned SQL, C and Python. I also tinkered with OS and familiarised myself with Linux, command line tools and server management. I went on to do a couple of internships in App dev, server management and made quite a few websites. I, however, had a desire to shift towards something related to astronomy, but whenever I delve into topics to try my hands on, I cannot figure out why I should choose this and not that!! I am fascinated by almost anything, and that doesn't help. I tried getting a casual read of an undergraduate course textbook at the suggestion of one of my professors, (Astronomy: A Physical Perspective by Marc L. Kutner (Author)). I enjoyed the read but mostly skipped the General Relativity part. I was most fascinated by the chapters on stellar evolution and galaxy formations. To probe more into the topics, I inquired my professors and started reading ([https://www.astro.umd.edu/~richard/ASTRO620/MBW_Book_Galaxy.pdf](https://www.astro.umd.edu/%7Erichard/ASTRO620/MBW_Book_Galaxy.pdf)) a book on Galaxy Formation and Evolution. However, it stopped making sense after 2.5 chapters, and I felt my knowledge of mathematics and physics was lacking.

What I wanted to ask was, when I am trying to look for internship opportunities, I am intimidated by the topics people are working on and hardly have any clue, so how do I really get into doing actual stuff? How would I approach people in granting me an opportunity to get my hands dirty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internship in Astronomy, with a degree in physics?

Get your hands dirty: do an internship related to the astronomy hardware (optics, electronics, hardware). Since India has an ambitious space plan, there must be tons of opportunities.

By knowing a little bit about what and how you need to observe something, you will start understand what it is the ultimate goal of the research.

Comment: The problem is not knowing the thing beforehand, if I approach a professor wanting to try out stuff and do an internship but I hardly have any knowledge, how do I convince him/her to giving me a chance?

Comment: Professors are used to undergrads not having experience. Comes with the territory…

Comment: @KartikMandar the question you are asking is not the one you asked! but the answer from JonCuster is what you need to know, i.e. you need not to worry.